# Interpolating when the gaps are variable

Tags: excel, function, interpolation

Ok, ChatGPT and MS Copilot are unable to help despite several iterations.  Google searches here and elsewhere haven't turned up anything I've found to be useful. So maybe a real brain can help figure this out (that's you!)

I have a small column of numerical data (n <= 10) that is collected from a table using Index/Match.  There are gaps in the data which I need to linearly interpolate with an Excel formula.  The gaps can be anywhere from one to three or four cells in size and they won't always be in the same location (not in the same rows for each set of results).  Any meaningful data will be increase in value as you proceed down the rows.  In another column, I need the formula to:

1. return the same value if there is one present already
2. if there is no value present, then it fills in the blank(s) with a linear interpolation
   2.1  [(next value) - (previous value) / (number of rows between next and previous values)] + (previous value)

...and so on down the rows.

Is this possible in an Excel formula?   I could switch to VBA if this isn't feasible in a formula.

Thanks!

---

**Examples that AI has suggested, but there were always too many or too few arguments for the function:**
(column F contains days/rows, I contains the data, J is the target cells)

```
=IF(ISBLANK(I2), FORECAST.LINEAR(J2, INDEX(I:I, MIN(IF(I:I<>"", ROW(I:I)))), INDEX(J:J, MIN(IF(I:I<>"", ROW(I:I)))) : INDEX(J:J, MAX(IF(I:I<>"", ROW(I:I)))), INDEX(I:I, MIN(IF(I:I<>"", ROW(I:I)))) : INDEX(I:I, MAX(IF(I:I<>"", ROW(I:I))))), I2)
```

```
=IF(ISBLANK(I2), FORECAST(J2, INDEX(I:I, SMALL(IF(I:I<>"", ROW(I:I)-ROW($I$2)+1))), INDEX(J:J, SMALL(IF(I:I<>"", ROW(I:I)-ROW($I$2)+1)))), I2)
```

```
=IF(ISBLANK(I2), INDEX(LINEST(INDEX($I$2:$I$12, N(IF({1}, SMALL(IF($I$2:$I$12<>"", ROW($I$2:$I$12)-ROW($I$2)+1)))), INDEX($J$2:$J$12, N(IF({1}, SMALL(IF($I$2:$I$12<>"", ROW($I$2:$I$12)-ROW($I$2)+1))))), 2, 1) * J2 + INDEX(LINEST(INDEX($I$2:$I$12, N(IF({1}, SMALL(IF($I$2:$I$12<>"", ROW($I$2:$I$12)-ROW($I$2)+1)))), INDEX($J$2:$J$12, N(IF({1}, SMALL(IF($I$2:$I$12<>"", ROW($I$2:$I$12)-ROW($I$2)+1))))), 2, 2), I2)
```

**[This formula "works", but the values returned are not properly/evenly interpolated:]**

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(I2), I2, IFERROR(FORECAST.LINEAR(F2,IF(ISNUMBER(I$2:I$12),I$2:I$12,""),F$2:F$12), ""))
```

Comment: please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) . Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

This will only work if the numbers are ascending.

`MAX` and `MIN` to find the previous and next non-blank numbers

`MATCH` to find the position of the previous and next non-blank numbers

Subtract and divide to work out the increments

`IF` `ISNUMBER` to determine if the formula will use the actual number or interpolate a number.

Formula in B2 is:

```
=LET(
PREV,MAX($A$2:A2),
NEXT,MIN(A2:$A$11),
GAP,MATCH(NEXT,$A$2:$A$11,0)-MATCH(PREV,$A$2:$A$11,0),
IF(ISNUMBER(A2),A2,(NEXT-PREV)/(GAP)+B1))
```

[image]